# How do use Run query and list results and get value into a Initialize variable

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

My query returns this value

[image: Image desc]

And i want to get the value of **Count** in a variable on Initialize variable(workflow expression) and use the value that on a condition control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parse Json in this case. Here is the screen shot of my logic app.

To get the inner values you can use the below expression inside Initialize variable

```
body('Parse_JSON')?['value'][0]?['Count']
```

[image]

Here is the output

[image]